# Can I deploy an application developed using Watson API without Bluemix?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I want to deploy a text to speech application using the Watson API, is that possible without using Bluemix?

I tried a demo application using Bluemix, it worked fine, no issues ..

http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/text-to-speech/sample.shtml#usingClientCode

But the problem is I want to run the application without using Bluemix,
is that possible???

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can actually.  You will still need to provision a Watson service through Bluemix but you can access it outside of the Bluemix.  When you create the Watson service you want in Bluemix you can bind the service to an existing application (or) create a dummy application to get Watson service credentials from Environment variables of the application.